# Refresh state of another class on popback navigation

Tags: flutter

I have an app which holds a scaffold in one class and the body of the widget in another.  One of the buttons on the scaffold opens up a settings menu to change display settings.  Since this button is on the scaffold, and the body is in another class, I cannot get the body to reset its state and rebuild after returning from the settings menu.  How should I tell the LocalCalculator class to setState from within the ScaffoldCalc class?

```
class _ScaffoldCalcState extends State<ScaffoldCalc> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkDisclaimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ExcludeSemantics(
          excluding: showCalcDisclaimer,
          child:Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Local Anesthetic Calculator'),
                backgroundColor: MyColors.PrimaryColor1,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings, semanticLabel: "Settings Menu",),
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.fullAutoMode();
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsMenu()),
                      ).then((value) {
                        //Run after return from settings
                        AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ]
            ),
            body: LocalCalculator(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class LocalCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LACalcState();
  }
}

class _LACalcState extends State<LocalCalculator> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  //Build our widget tree
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          bupivacaine.hideEditing();
          ropivacaine.hideEditing();
          mepivacaine.hideEditing();
          lidocaine.hideEditing();
          chloroprocaine.hideEditing();
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            //CalcHeader(),
            WeightDisplay(),
            DrugCardHeader(),
            DrugCardList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you need to change any Widget For example whole-app, There was
>   some task after completing, that we ceed to refresh the app.
>
> Use setState(), setState() are refresh your whole state of widgets and
>   as your code you can write setState after your **Navigator Then** .

setState rebuild your body and reload all widgets.

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsMenu()))
.then((value) {
  //Run after return from settings
  setState(() {});
  AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
});
```

Comment: This does not work as I am trying to refresh the state of a different class.

Answer (score 0):

While **setState** works fantastic for managing state within a stateful widget class , you can go with better state management approaches like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) when trying to share a common state between multiple widget classes.

Flutter takes care of reloading all your widgets (that use this state) with the updated values whenever the state is changed. See this [state management demo](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) from flutter for more details.

Check this sample code that extends provider support to manage state of a **counter** inside `Settings` page and value being updated in `LocalCalculator` page.

> Do not forget to bind the provider **MyProvider** in the runApp method in main class

```
class ScaffoldCalc extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ScaffoldCalcState();
  }
}

class _ScaffoldCalcState extends State<ScaffoldCalc> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ExcludeSemantics(
          excluding: false,
          child:Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Local Anesthetic Calculator'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings, semanticLabel: "Settings Menu",),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsPage()),
                      ).then((value) {
                        //Run after return from settings
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ]
            ),
            body: LocalCalculator(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SettingsPageState();
  }

}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("New page"),),
      floatingActionButton: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        spacing: 10.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "fab-add",
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Provider.of<MyProvider>(context,listen: false).increment();
            },
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "fab-subtract",
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: (){
              Provider.of<MyProvider>(context,listen: false).decrement();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}

class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double state = 1.0;

  void increment() {
    state += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    state -= 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

class LocalCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LACalcState();
  }
}

class _LACalcState extends State<LocalCalculator> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  //Build our widget tree
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Count is : ${Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).state}"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting plugin I haven't seen before. I'll look into it. Thanks for the advice.